# "They paint their sheep". Is that the correct way to mean "They make the sheep colorful" rather than "They create a picture of sheep on a surface"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, word-choice, idiomatic-language

Some farmers put a colour on their sheep herd not to confuse them with sheep of other farmers.

So, to say this shortly, what comes to my mind is: **"They paint the sheep**", but I am not quite sure, because it might mean **"They produce a picture of sheep on a surface"** rather than actually making their sheep to have the some colours.

So, is the sentence **"They paint the sheep** the correct way to say it without being ambugious? If not, what would be the correct way.

Comment: We would not say: paint their sheep. That implies the entire animal. Please see this: https://quillcards.com/blog/smit-marks-to-identify-sheep/#:~:text=They%20are%20smit%20marks%20and,which%20belonged%20to%20his%20neighbour. That link is for the UK but I'd say for AmE: paint marks on them even though some sites on the internet do have: paint their sheep.

Comment: They're not big enough numbers to be statistically significant, but Google returns just 2 hits for ["some farmers **paint** their sheep"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=%22some+farmers+paint+their+sheep%22), but **6** hits for ["some farmers **dye** their sheep"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=%22some+farmers+dye+their+sheep%22).

Comment: This question is pointless - it's a *hypothetical* "ambiguity" that would never lead to confusion in the real world. And I shouldn't think any farmer would be likely to daub his sheep with "paint" today, anyway. It would ruin the wool, and Health and Safety checks would probably prevent the animal (or its milk) being sold for human consumption!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps it would seem less pointless in another context? For example, festival-goers might pay an artist to paint their faces. Someone else might specialize in painting buildings. And so on.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: They might. But each *exact* context would be different, and obviously English doesn't have a standard default way of indicating whether the verb ***paint*** is being used in its *create a depiction / painting* sense OR something like *apply pigment to the subject*. In some contexts we might decide to unambiguously convey the first sense by ***depict, portray,...*** or the second by ***dye, stain,...*** But there is no "generic" solution. Learners just need to understand that many English words have multiple meanings. If there's *meaningfully* unwanted ambiguity, *rephrase*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers coloured markings are frequently seen on ewes which indicate that they have been tupped. If the rams were provided with different colour paints on their harness you can tell which ram tupped which ewe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to paint marks on sheep

> Type and colour of animal: ear tag numbers, ear notches and colour of
> paint marks on sheep; brand marks on ponies; ear tag numbers and ear
> notches on cattle.

A UK site but also works in AmE.

They put paint marks on their sheep. They mark their sheep with paint.

[dlps.org](https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm)

[A UK site but also works in AmE](https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm)

They put paint marks on their sheep.
They mark their sheep with paint.

Smit marks, US

to paint marks on sheep

> Type and colour of animal: ear tag numbers, ear notches and colour of
> paint marks on sheep; brand marks on ponies; ear tag numbers and ear
> notches on cattle.
> [US casualty report](https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm)

[A UK site but also works in AmE](https://quillcards.com/blog/smit-marks-to-identify-sheep/#:%7E:text=They%20are%20smit%20marks%20and,which%20belonged%20to%20his%20neighbour)

They put paint marks on their sheep.
They mark their sheep with paint.

**Smit Marks** or paint marks  UK

> If you have seen sheep in the lowland fields and on the hills in the
> UK you may have noticed the paint marks on their fleeces. They are
> smit marks and farmers have been using them for hundreds of years to
> identify who sheep belong to.
>
> A daub of paint – perhaps two marks of red or one of black – nearer
> the haunch or the shoulder. From these a farmer would know which were
> his sheep and which belonged to his neighbour.
>
> The paint was a mixture of a pigment to give the colour and grease or
> whale oil to make the mixture stick.

[British website](https://quillcards.com/blog/smit-marks-to-identify-sheep/#:%7E:text=They%20are%20smit%20marks%20and,which%20belonged%20to%20his%20neighbour)

[Dartmoor Livestock Protection Society_ UK](https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm)
https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm

> Any member of the public or police can help - please call assistance
> quickly. Payment for initial veterinary aid for injured moorland
> livestock is guaranteed by the Dartmoor Livestock Protection Society.
>
> It is important to give the following details, where possible: Type
> and colour of animal: ear tag numbers, ear notches and colour of **paint
> marks** on sheep; brand marks on ponies; ear tag numbers and ear notches
> on cattle.

[image: Dales Discoveries]
DALES DISCOVERIES

> Farmers used paint marks to differentiate their sheep from others. It
> was originally a combination of pigment and grease so the colour
> stayed on. Chemical sprays are now more commonly used. Each farmer
> would devise their own shape or combination of stripes.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence "They paint their sheep" is indeed ambiguous, and without context, could have either meaning. But in the context of farmers marking their sheep to differentiate them from those of other farmers, "They paint their sheep" is fine.

If you want an unambiguous term that means "put paint on sheep to mark them as your property", you can use "brand".

> They **brand** their sheep with paint.

This word "brand" in this sense usually means to use very hot metal to burn a recognizable shape into an animal's skin, but it's also used for the practice of marking sheep with paint.

Answer (score 2):

to paint marks on sheep

> Type and colour of animal: ear tag numbers, ear notches and colour of
> paint marks on sheep; brand marks on ponies; ear tag numbers and ear
> notches on cattle.

[A UK site but also works in AmE](https://www.dlps.org.uk/report_casualty.htm)

They put paint marks on their sheep.
They mark their sheep with paint.

Comment: "to paint marks on their sheep" or "to put paint marks on their sheep" or both?

Comment: @yunus to paint marks on sheep. You don't really put a mark of paint on something...